# How to make file downloadable from server to Front End in Spring Boot project, Created Rest API for file downloading but not functioning as expected?

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, kotlin, download

In general, I have created rest controller for both uploading and downloading a file from front end (React) to our file system. Uploading works great, as expected. However, downloading rest api not functioning properly. it downloads only 12kb or smth like that of the file. Is there anything [configs] that I am missing in my project or what? Please help! any comment or suggestion would be appreciated thanks in advance

```
@GetMapping("/get")
    fun getFile(@Valid data: FileDeleteDTO): ResponseEntity<Resource>{

        val header = HttpHeaders()

        val fileGetFromDb =  baseFileUploaderAttachmentService.getByUid(data.qquuid)
        if (!fileGetFromDb.isPresent)
            throw FileNotFoundException()
        val pathFileName = fileGetFromDb.get().filename + '.' + fileGetFromDb.get().extension
        val originalFileName = fileGetFromDb.get().originalName + '.' + fileGetFromDb.get().extension
//        val filePath = UPLOAD_ROOT_FOLDER + fileGetFromDb.get().path + pathFileName
        val filePath = UPLOAD_ROOT_FOLDER + fileGetFromDb.get().path
//        val file = File(filePath)
        header.contentType = (MediaType.valueOf(fileGetFromDb.get().mime_type!!))
        header.contentLength = fileGetFromDb.get().size
        header.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=$originalFileName")

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .headers(header)
                    .body(loadFileAsResource(pathFileName,Paths.get(filePath)))

    }


    fun loadFileAsResource(fileName: String, fileStorageLocation: Path): Resource {

        try {
            val filePath = fileStorageLocation.resolve(fileName).normalize()
            val resource = UrlResource(filePath.toUri())
            return if (resource.exists()) {
                resource
            } else {
                throw FileNotFoundException("File not found $fileName")
            }
        } catch (ex: MalformedURLException) {
            throw Exception("File not found $fileName", ex)
        }

    }
```

> [image: This is the result from Insomnia which shows the result in which only some part of image is downloaded]

Comment: Perhaps, your resource does not have match time to gather fully and only part of it is sent. Try to debug method 'loadFileAsResource' and look inside, what is he returned.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, I have debugged more than enough. I was wondering  whether it is  linked to keeping connection alive or smth like that, When i have tried downloading this file on browser, at first it downloads some part of it quickly like 100KB out of 150 and remained 50KB so slowly like 6kb per second I dont get it tbh.  to @Scrobot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have no idea what happened but i have solved above problem by adding some header elements like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = ["/download"], method = [RequestMethod.GET])
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun downloadFile(@Valid data: FileDeleteDTO): ResponseEntity<Any> {

    val fileGetFromDb =  baseFileUploaderAttachmentService.getByUid(data.qquuid)
    val pathFileName = fileGetFromDb.get().filename + '.' + fileGetFromDb.get().extension
    val originalFileName = fileGetFromDb.get().originalName + '.' + fileGetFromDb.get().extension

    val filePath = UPLOAD_ROOT_FOLDER + fileGetFromDb.get().path + pathFileName

    val file = File(filePath)

    val resource = InputStreamResource(FileInputStream(file))
    val headers = HttpHeaders()

    headers.add("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", originalFileName))
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
    headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache")
    headers.add("Expires", "0")

    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentLength(
        file.length()
    ).contentType((MediaType.valueOf(fileGetFromDb.get().mime_type!!))).body(resource)
}
```

> Just wondering does Cache control has impact on this issue? Where can i learn about headers?